# Thermodynamic potentials and Entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, potential, entropy

Is there a more intuitive way to explain the thermodynamic potentials, $G$ (Gibbs free energy) and $H$ (Helmholtz free energy).

I think the major problem having with the explanations is because i need  to understand entropy change too in a more intuitive manner.

What I would like to understand in case of Entropy is how is it the energy obtained by spontaneous heat transfer from the environment to the system.

how does entropy change correspond to the environment or the system and how does it affect the creation of a system.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149493

Comment: You are aware that entropy is a physical property of the material comprising the system, and not a feature of the heat exchanged, right?

Comment: yes thank you @Chemomechanics