# Gibbs free energy of mixing with respect to temperature, is there a relation with lagrangian formulation of mechanics?

Tags: thermodynamics, lagrangian-formalism

The Gibbs free energy determins if two substances are miscible at certain temperature since it will get minimized:

$$ \Delta G = \Delta H - T \Delta S$$
Where $ \Delta G < 0$ determines if a process is spontaneous. This seems kind of similar to lagrangian mechanics where the action gets minimized:

$$ dS = \int (T-V) dt $$
Where $T-V=L$; the lagrangian.

Also if you look at the diagrams it almost seems like a path. Is this similarity coincidental? Or is this to be expected and actual two different formulations of the same thing?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/579239/236734

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [Legendre Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation)?

Comment: These are about thermodynamic potentials in general. I mean the lagrangian formulation. It seems like $T-V$ is similar to $dH-TdS$